# Как подписать на событие метод после того как исполнится created

Tags: vue.js

При загрузке страницы у меня в методе created в title записываться value, проблема в том что в сетере title так же есть метод который запускает валидацию `validationQuestionGroup`, из за этого у меня создаеться проблема когда пользователь заходит на страницу а у него уже все незаполненные поля провалидированны и с ошибками. Возможно ли както передавать значение title не на created?

```
<input v-model="title" type="text>

computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['getQuestionGroupTitle']),

        title: {
            set(value) {
                this.changeQuestionGroupTitle(value);
                this.validationQuestionGroup(value);
            },

            get() {
                return this.getQuestionGroupTitle;
            },
        },
    },

    created() {
        if (this.item.fieldValue) this.title = this.item.fieldValue;
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['changeQuestionGroupTitle', 'validationQuestionGroup']),
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: () => ({
  /* ... */
  isMounted: false                                            // ◀
}), 
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['getQuestionGroupTitle']),
  title: {
    set(value) {
      this.changeQuestionGroupTitle(value);
      this.isMounted && this.validationQuestionGroup(value);  // ◀
    },
    get() {
      return this.getQuestionGroupTitle;
    },
  },
},
/* ... */
created() {
  if (this.item.fieldValue) 
    this.title = this.item.fieldValue;
},
mounted() {
  this.isMounted = true;                                      // ◀
}
```